# How To Specify ChainID

Tags: events, web3j, harmony

I am interacting with the Harmony testnet using web3j, but since Harmony has 4 shards i also have to specify the chainID, otherwise it throw an error.

When writing to the blockchain i was able of fixing this issue by specifying the chain ID in the txn manager

`TransactionManager tm = new RawTransactionManager(web3j, keyManagement.getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(), chainId);`

However when i want to subscribe to events on the blockchain, i can't seem to find out a way to specify the chainID, can anyone help me specify the chainID here.

This is usually the code we use to subscribe to events on the blockchain.

```
Main.Web3j.ethLogFlowable(filter).subscribe(event -> {}, error -> {
            System.out.println("Error: " + error);
        });
```

Comment: You don’t need the chainId for events and call functions? ChainId is probably only used to sign transactions

Comment: What error are you getting when calling `ethLogFlowable`? For many eth-compatible RPC this function works just fine.

Comment: Also, check that the node you're connecting to supports `eth_getFilterChanges` RPC command. Some public nodes(fantom, boba for instance) disabled that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here turned out to be a limitation on the amount of blocks i can read which turned out to be 1k.